# How To Export-Import Database in Oracle 11g(Application Express Edition)?

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, backup

I am beginner in Oracle 11g. I have created a database in oracle 11g(Application Express).

I want to export this database with all data(whole workspace) and import this to another computer where I already have installed Oracle.Is there any way to export-import the whole workspace in oracle 11g application express?

Answer (score 2):

You have lots of different options for doing this:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/admin.102/b25107/impexp.htm

I would recommend using Oracle Datapump as this is the most powerful solution, and would represent the best opportunity for instruction on how this is done in an enterprise environment.

Answer (score -3):

1. exp username/password@database name file=path (where you want to store the dump file)
2. exp username/password@database name file=path (where you want to store the dump file )statics=none